# Difference between Microsoft Test Manager 2010 and later versions

Tags: mtm

Can i find anywhere the differences or new features added in Microsoft Test Manager from 2010 version to 2015 version.

Differences between MTM 2010, 2013 and 2015

Answer (score 3):

**1. Visual Studio 2010:**

Three products provide testing functionality in Visual Studio 2010:
Visual Studio Test Professional:  This is primarily for the generalist tester who wants to create manual test cases, run these tests and view the results as part of a test plan. The key application is MTM.

Visual Studio 2010 Premium: This provides the features to enable a user to create unit tests and UI automated tests for an application.
Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate: This contains all the test functionality provided for Visual Studio 2010. It includes MTM providing the functionality for planning, creating, and running test cases. It also enables you to create and run unit tests, UI automated tests, load tests and Web performance tests, generic tests and ordered tests using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

For testers, VS 2010 provide new tool called MTM, MTM is contained in two VS products, Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate and Visual Studio Test Professional 2010. You install VS 2010 Ultimate, MTM is installed by default.

MTM need to integrate with TFS, then you can create test plan, test suites, test case, run manual test, run automatic test in lab.

while,

**2. Visual Studio 2012:**

Visual Studio 2012 introduces new test project templates. In Visual Studio 2010, there was a single test project template.

Visual Studio 2012 has these test project templates:
Unit Test Project – Can include unit tests, third-party unit tests, ordered tests, and generic tests.
Coded UI Test Project – Can include the test types listed for Unit Test Project above, and coded UI tests.

Web Performance and Load Test Project – Can include Web performance tests and load tests.

Answer (score 2):

The added features from 2010 to 2013 are listed in [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/softwaresimian/2014/08/22/features-added-in-microsoft-test-manager-20102013/).

I don't find anything relevant to the 2015 edition, so it's possible that they didn't update a lot of functionalities, or the documentation is poor or hidden somewhere.
On [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635157(v=vs.140).aspx) however, you can switch between the 2015 version and older ones.